# Objective-C >> Is There a Way to Get a Pointer / Variable Name as an NSString?

Tags: objective-c, instance-variables, introspection

Is there a way to ask a pointer / variable for its name as a string?

i.e...

```
NSNumber* aNumber;
int anInt;

NSString* name = aFunctionThatDoesWhatIAskedFor(aNumber);
NSLog(@"%@",name); //should print "aNumber";

name = aFunctionThatDoesWhatIAskedFor(anInt);
NSLog(@"%@",name); //should print "anInt";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

define this macro

```
#define nameOfVariable(x) NSLog( @"%s",#x)
```

use this macro

```
nameOfVariable(aNumber);
nameOfVariable(anInt);
```

**Explanation:**

Preceding parameter name by # is known as ***Stringification***. You can use the ‘#’ operator to stringify the variable argument or to paste its token with another token.

> Sometimes you may want to convert a macro argument into a string
>   constant. Parameters are not replaced inside string constants, but you
>   can use the `#' preprocessing operator instead. When a macro parameter
>   is used with a leading`#', the preprocessor replaces it with the
>   literal text of the actual argument, converted to a string constant.
>   Unlike normal parameter replacement, the argument is not
>   macro-expanded first. This is called *[stringification](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.0.1/cpp_3.html#SEC17)*.

Comment: # has special meaning when used in a macro.
#  means quote the following token (which should be a macro parameter name). your macro is same as NSLog( @"%s","aNumber");

Answer (score 0):

In most programming languages objects don't have names.